# Doing a PIVOT table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Seems like it should be really easy to change this one row data:

```
SalesTotal Refunds  Discount Taxes  
63093.05   -102.52  3905.11  2523.32
```

Into this:

```
SalesTotal  63093.05
Refunds      -102.52
Discount     3905.11
Taxes        2523.32
```

Using the PIVOT in SQL.
But... in all the examples I found;

http://www.izenda.com/Site/KB/FAQ/How-do-I-create-a-pivot-table-in-Microsoft-SQL-
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/22/sql-server-pivot-table-example/
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1019/crosstab-queries-using-pivot-in-sql-server/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.105).aspx
Etc....

there was the need of doing addition aggregates in the PIVOT command.
All I am wanting to do is turn the table on its side.

Any way of doing that?

Comment: That's because you should be looking for `UNPIVOT`

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking for `UNPIVOT` instead. Here is a way of getting the results you want with `CROSS APPLY` (this assumes that all of your columns have a compatible data type):

```
SELECT  x.Col,
        x.Value
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES
        ('SalesTotal', t.SalesTotal),
        ('Refunds', t.Refunds),
        ('Discount', t.Discount),
        ('Taxes', t.Taxes)
) x(Col, Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `UNPIVOT` not `PIVOT` to rotate columns into rows

```
SELECT Type, value from
(SELECT * from Table1) T
UNPIVOT
( value for Type in ( [SalesTotal], [Refunds], [Discount], [Taxes])
) unpvt
```